# Generated JAR file - JNI error has occurred intellij

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I've created a maze for a project i've to do to pass an exam, when i try to generate a jar file and i try to run i've got this problem: JNI error has occurred.
Someone can help me? i don't know what to do i'm using intellij and jdk 20, when i try to run it by java -jar Maze.jar in the terminal it just crush. I'm using also sqlite in this project with javafx.

[image]

[image: My project:]

to start jar file, for exporting my project.

Comment: Further info is in the runtime images section of the getting started documentation at openjfx.io.